# Get closing parenthesis of a multi-line method invocation aligned line containing the opening parenthesis

Tags: c#, coding-style, resharper

This is one of many Resharper indentation setting questions. I have got almost everything correctly formatted to my style, except a multiline method invocation, and to be exact, the closing parenthesis. Right now, Resharper formats it in this way:

```
MethodCall(
    param1,
    param2
    );

var customers =
    new XElement("customers",
        new XElement("customer", new XAttribute("id", 1),
            new XElement("name", "Sue"),
            new XElement("buys", 3)
            )
        );
```

I am trying to get the closing parenthesis aligned with the line containing the opening parenthesis:

```
MethodCall(
    param1,
    param2
);

var customers =
    new XElement("customers",
        new XElement("customer", new XAttribute("id", 1),
            new XElement("name", "Sue"),
            new XElement("buys", 3)
        )
    );
```

Is there any way to get it?

Comment: Not sure if this one's possible.  People have been asking for a similar formatting for years, though: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-260807

Comment: It seems this is not currently possible with ReSharper, though it appears to be in the works. See the answer I posted on a related question here: [Resharper closing parenthesis indentation on function with multiple arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637290/resharper-closing-parenthesis-indentation-on-function-with-multiple-arguments/30129366#30129366)